# Finding standard deviation $\sigma$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Carton of mlik  can be reserved fresh for $20$ days in average, $\frac13$ from the milk cartons can reserved fresh for $22$ days or more.

> Let's assume that the period of fresh is normaly distribued
>
> find the standard deviation $\sigma$

---

**My attempt:**

$$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$

$$E[X]=\mu=20$$

$$\text{Var}[X]=\sigma^2$$

$$X\sim N(20,\sigma^2)$$

The cumulative distribution function:

$$\Phi\bigg(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)=\Phi\bigg(\frac{1/3-20}{\sigma}\bigg)\geq22$$

> Is it correct so far? I don't know how to proceed and finding $\sigma$

Comment: Your last formula is wonky. It should be $\Pr(X\ge 22) = 1/3$

Comment: How it could help me find $\sigma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac13 = \Pr(X \ge 22) = 1 - \Pr(X < 22) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{22-\mu}{\sigma}\right). $$

Now, there are tables for values of $\Phi$ or just ask wolfram alpha.

Comment: What should I write in wolfram

Comment: @Nehorai "invnorm probability = 2/3"

Answer (score 2):

You have $p(X>22)=\frac 13\Rightarrow p(z>\frac{22-20}{\sigma})=\frac 13$

Therefore $$\frac{22-20}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(\frac 23)=0.43$$